# Actionscript3 - Socket issue

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, ip

I made an AIR application (actually it's big and that's why I didn't post the code here), in the application I used the Socket class to send data, and also created a ServerSocket object to receive the data. Everything works fine and the data sent and received successfully but, the problem is when I tried to get the remote IP (the sender ip) using the remoteAddress property, it gave the local ip of the router which is 192.168.1.1, the IP I expected to get is the public IP which is something like this: 60.96.190.82. So is this normal or there is something??

Comment: This looks to me like it's network related, not very much Flash related. Please try to explain in more detail where the server and the client are located, in relation to your router/local network.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/retrieving_network_interfaces.html) should help you. Cycle through results[i].addresses and ignore local addresses.